# pabot:: is it possible to send a --variablefile <<filename>>instead of --variable key:value inside --argumentfile option?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, parallel-processing, robotframework

I need to send a list of 100 variables which are already in a variable file to pabot **as part of argument file argument** as shown below, the reason we are making use of argumentfiles is that , we have configurations which are coming from multiple machines that are in their own variables file, we are planning to create multiple argumentfile for the respective machines and initiate testsuites on all the machines at once. Hence, we are looking for embedding variablesfile inside an argumentsfile instead of providing all 100 variables as individual key value pairs.

According to pabot documentation, --variablefile is not supported, when i make use of --variablefile instead of --variable , i see the following error. is there any otherway we can pass variablesfile inside argumentsfile? OR is there any other better approach to achieve this?

```
(rf0) apachemain@apachemain:~$ pabot --verbose --argumentfile1 ./mdc/arg1.txt --argumentfile2 ./mdc/arg2.txt --ordering order mdc/
Storing .pabotsuitenames file
2020-01-04 15:03:32.220331 [PID:23265] [0] EXECUTING PARALLEL Mdc.1 with command:
robot --suite Mdc.1 --variable CALLER_ID:c397cfb742024ae0aa2eb2a58b36faa4 --variable PABOTLIBURI:127.0.0.1:8270 --variable PABOTEXECUTIONPOOLID:0 --variable PABOTISLASTEXECUTIONINPOOL:0 --variable PABOTQUEUEINDEX:0 --variable PABOTLASTLEVEL:Mdc.1.PABOT_noend --argumentfile ./mdc/arg1.txt --log NONE --report NONE --xunit NONE --outputdir ./pabot_results/1/Mdc.1 --consolecolors off --consolemarkers off mdc/
2020-01-04 15:03:32.221311 [PID:23267] [1] EXECUTING PARALLEL Mdc.1 with command:
robot --suite Mdc.1 --variable CALLER_ID:932a7b6049644ab48269677d147a5f84 --variable PABOTLIBURI:127.0.0.1:8270 --variable PABOTEXECUTIONPOOLID:1 --variable PABOTISLASTEXECUTIONINPOOL:1 --variable PABOTQUEUEINDEX:1 --variable PABOTLASTLEVEL: --argumentfile ./mdc/arg2.txt --log NONE --report NONE --xunit NONE --outputdir ./pabot_results/2/Mdc.1 --consolecolors off --consolemarkers off mdc/
2020-01-04 15:03:32.523013 [PID:23265] [0] Execution failed in Mdc.1 with 252 failing test(s)

[ ERROR ] option --variablefile /home/apachemain/mdc/var1.py not recognized

Try --help for usage information.
```

**This is what am looking for**

```
pabot --verbose --argumentfile1 ./dc1/arg1.txt --argumentfile2 ./dc1/arg2.txt dc_suites/

Inside respective argumentfile
cat arg1.txt 
--variablefile  /home/apachemain/dc/var1.py
```

I have done the following making using [pabot](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-pabot/).

**Actual Behavior**
pabot command used to execute tests inside dc1 dir.

```
pabot --verbose --argumentfile1 ./dc/arg1.txt dc1/
```

According to pabot documentation, only --variable key:value can be provided, a file reference cannot be provided, is there we can pass variablefile instead of --variable inside argumentfile for pabot?

```
(base) apachemain@apachemain:~/dc$ cat arg1.txt 
--variable var_num1:1
--variable var_num2:1
```

```
(base) ain@apain:~/mdc$ cat arg1.txt 
-d myoutputdir
--variable var_num1:1
--variable var_num2:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of searching documentation and looking for answers on the web, the issue ended up with space. This is one of the things they could have really improved about the framework. This is pretty frustrating!!

The issue is with space(NOT TAB) in between option  --variablefile FILENAME

```
(rf0) apachemain@apachemain:~$ cat mdc/arg1.txt 
-d myoutputdir
--variablefile /home/apachemain/mdc/var1.py
```

```
(rf0) apachemain@apachemain:~$ pabot --verbose --argumentfile1 ./mdc/arg1.txt --argumentfile2 ./mdc/arg2.txt --ordering order mdc/
2020-01-06 17:48:59.838817 [PID:4352] [0] EXECUTING PARALLEL Mdc.1 with command:
robot --suite Mdc.1 --variable CALLER_ID:5aa460eebf614bff829949acc94caa7d --variable PABOTLIBURI:127.0.0.1:8270 --variable PABOTEXECUTIONPOOLID:0 --variable PABOTISLASTEXECUTIONINPOOL:1 --variable PABOTQUEUEINDEX:1 --variable PABOTLASTLEVEL: --argumentfile ./mdc/arg2.txt --log NONE --report NONE --xunit NONE --outputdir ./pabot_results/2/Mdc.1 --consolecolors off --consolemarkers off mdc/
2020-01-06 17:48:59.839717 [PID:4354] [1] EXECUTING PARALLEL Mdc.1 with command:
robot --suite Mdc.1 --variable CALLER_ID:8ab39f105c594a4e8f7448ba5bce81ee --variable PABOTLIBURI:127.0.0.1:8270 --variable PABOTEXECUTIONPOOLID:1 --variable PABOTISLASTEXECUTIONINPOOL:0 --variable PABOTQUEUEINDEX:0 --variable PABOTLASTLEVEL:Mdc.1.PABOT_noend --argumentfile ./mdc/arg1.txt --log NONE --report NONE --xunit NONE --outputdir ./pabot_results/1/Mdc.1 --consolecolors off --consolemarkers off mdc/
2020-01-06 17:49:00.141353 [PID:4352] [0] PASSED Mdc.1 in 0.3 seconds
==============================================================================
Mdc                                                                           
==============================================================================
Mdc.1                                                                         
==============================================================================
ADD TWO NUMBERS                                                       11+11
| PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mdc.1                                                                 | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Mdc                                                                   | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /home/apachemain/pabot_results/2/Mdc.1/output.xml


2020-01-06 17:49:00.143912 [PID:4354] [1] PASSED Mdc.1 in 0.3 seconds
==============================================================================
Mdc                                                                           
==============================================================================
Mdc.1                                                                         
==============================================================================
ADD TWO NUMBERS                                                       1+1
| PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mdc.1                                                                 | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Mdc                                                                   | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /home/apachemain/pabot_results/1/Mdc.1/output.xml


Output:  /home/apachemain/output.xml
Log:     /home/apachemain/log.html
Report:  /home/apachemain/report.html
Total testing: 0.60 seconds
Elapsed time:  0.44 seconds
```